# Android RSA Encryption throws InvalidKeySpecException

Tags: android, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to encrypt data using a given public key.

```
public static final String public_key = "MIIBCgKCAQEAr/oYAoxIcXnLzVDNN6TPJVjkwOJZnDcSEeoRntqhOvgjiycfswMWZZ5+UClJ4CMgMCVAs71BzAJzPv902Jt763SPkAO/vh6CwfLq2S3YcqDoRQJYZuSKQHW40R6sN7eFvQdxYhJnF45ketCdLdPFuF5o/ieChwLcCEDKzkWD7xio2TQlZ8jfzB4jNGr6bmW/aqF5ihe0pbhtfvlyM+jNF2vWeB1SCJ4v5zHLNKKYNy4cMsmIGHKB+0BaGVz87eYp65FFc2K9LawBBbWtVCxykYBzEnXRuU+0YzcTi4LThXg1cUsf++LK9qL/G7PZdN6HMGP7DYzgstFLfp8VRpKhqQIDAQAB";

String encryptData(String txt)
{
    String encoded = null;
    try {
        PublicKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(
                new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(public_key, Base64.DEFAULT)));

        Cipher cph = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cph.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        encoded = Base64.encodeToString(cph.doFinal(txt.getBytes()),
                Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encoded;
}
```

And  get the error

```
W/System.err: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPublicKey(OpenSSLKey.java:143)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.java:47)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:172)
```

I have used the same public key in Python3, with the 'BEGIN PUBLIC KEY...END PUBLIC KEY' header/footer and it works fine:

```
public_key = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAr/oYAoxIcXnLzVDNN6TPJVjkwOJZnDcSEeoRntqhOvgjiycfswMWZZ5+UClJ4CMgMCVAs71BzAJzPv902Jt763SPkAO/vh6CwfLq2S3YcqDoRQJYZuSKQHW40R6sN7eFvQdxYhJnF45ketCdLdPFuF5o/ieChwLcCEDKzkWD7xio2TQlZ8jfzB4jNGr6bmW/aqF5ihe0pbhtfvlyM+jNF2vWeB1SCJ4v5zHLNKKYNy4cMsmIGHKB+0BaGVz87eYp65FFc2K9LawBBbWtVCxykYBzEnXRuU+0YzcTi4LThXg1cUsf++LK9qL/G7PZdN6HMGP7DYzgstFLfp8VRpKhqQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
"""

def encode(msg):
    rsa_key = RSA.importKey(public_key)
    pks1_v1_5 = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsa_key)
    encrypted = pks1_v1_5.encrypt(msg.encode('utf-8'))
    encrypted = base64.b64encode(encrypted)
    return encrypted
```

Can someone help me out plz?

--- EDIT ---

I did some debugging on the Python code: stepping into 'RSA.importKey(public_key)' I see it recognizes the key as PEM encoded key, removes the header/footer and converts it to binary (binascii.a2b_base64). The binary is passed to RSA._importKeyDER which discovers that it follows the PKCS#1 standard and, in comment, 'The DER object is an RSAPublicKey SEQUENCE with two elements'.

Comment: Your key is not in the correct format for X509EncodedKeySpec. The simplest fix is to put it into the correct format.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I get the public key from another system via HTTP request and I have tested and succeeded to encrypt using this key with the Python3 code in my post.

Comment: Excellent, than you can do `rsa_key.export_key(format='DER')` from your python code and the result will be in the correct format for Java's X509EncodedKeySpec.

Comment: @JamesKPolk problem is that the public_key is not static, as in the code above, I receive it from an HTTP request and it is not the same every time, so I need to find the Java way to correctly get the RSA key from the public key I receive

Comment: Well, then you are going to have to write some code to convert it. The Bouncycastle Java library can do most of the work for you, if you can use it in your project.

Comment: why was I down-voted for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Are you generate your public key from openssl, since your public key is too long:

for example i generated from openssl and replace your public key, and everything fine:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024

openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout > key.pub
```

and paste key.pub string in your code.

Comment: I receive the public_key from another system, I need to encode data using their public key, so I don't know how they generate it.